# How to crack the password of a zip which is protected with a password?

Tags: password, zip

I have installed `fcrackzip`. The help page of `fcrackzip` says

```
$ fcrackzip --h

fcrackzip version 1.0, a fast/free zip password cracker
written by Marc Lehmann <pcg@goof.com> You can find more info on*emphasized text*
http://www.goof.com/pcg/marc/

USAGE: fcrackzip
          [-b|--brute-force]            use brute force algorithm
          [-D|--dictionary]             use a dictionary
          [-B|--benchmark]              execute a small benchmark
          [-c|--charset characterset]   use characters from charset
          [-h|--help]                   show this message
          [--version]                   show the version of this program
          [-V|--validate]               sanity-check the algortihm
          [-v|--verbose]                be more verbose
          [-p|--init-password string]   use string as initial password/file
          [-l|--length min-max]         check password with length min to max
          [-u|--use-unzip]              use unzip to weed out wrong passwords
          [-m|--method num]             use method number "num" (see below)
          [-2|--modulo r/m]             only calculcate 1/m of the password
          file...                    the zipfiles to crack

methods compiled in (* = default):

 0: cpmask
 1: zip1
*2: zip2, USE_MULT_TAB
```

How can I crack the zipfile which is protected with password with fcrackzip or any other available tool?

Comment: I think your answer lies in the question itself, the -h switch gives you the options as to how to use the tool with another file, if you need more info, try doing  `man fcrackzip`

Comment: i don't know that one also....pls  help me....

Comment: May be [this](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/fcrackzip.1.html)  would help you, it has examples too.

Comment: The answer is pretty much in the screenshot: `fcrackzip /path/to/file.zip`. use `--brute-force` or `--dictionary`` with it depending on what you need...

Comment: @JonasCz-ReinstateMonica Would you like to post an answer? If you do, ping me, I'll upvote :)

Answer (score 13):

There are a few ways to do this.

1. **fcrackzip**:  To brute force you can use

   ```
    fcrackzip -u -b -v file.zip
   ```

   The `-u` flag weeds out incorrect passwords, `-b` is for brute-forcing, `-l` is for specifying the password length, e.g: `4-8`.  You can use a password-list with the `-D` and `-p` flags, like so:

   ```
    fcrackzip -u -b -D -p /home/Desktop/passwordlist.txt file.zip
   ```
2. **RarCrack**:

   ```
    rarcrack --type zip/7z/rar file.zip
   ```

   I like this one as it saves cracking progress to a file called `yourfilename.zip.xml`, and will pick up where you left off when you next use it.
3. **John the Ripper**: Generate the hash first using

   ```
    zip2john file.zip > whateveryouwanttocallit.txt
   ```

   or use `rar2john`, depending on the file,
   and then:

   ```
    john --format=zip whateveryoucallit.txt
   ```

   or `--format=rar`.

   All of these can take a while depending on the length of the password, and the characters, but there you go.

   If any of these tools aren't installed, install them with

   ```
    sudo apt-get install rarcrack/john/fcrackzip
   ```

   If this is *still* not enough, you can download a fast Windows zip cracker, such as Passper for Zip, and run it with Wine.