# fcraczip no't working in ubuntu

Tags: files, zip, rar

i tried to crack my zip file it's not give me any result

this what i got

┌─[dsl@Linux]─[~/11]
└──╼ $fcrackzip -u -D -p 1 1.zip

┌─[dsl@Linux]─[~/11]
└──╼ $

[fcrackzip issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vuhas.png)

Comment: Are you sure your dictionary is named just "1"? `tldr fcrackzip` suggests `fcrackzip --use-unzip --dictionary --init-password wordlist archive`

Comment: yes it's 1  i tried this solution     https://askubuntu.com/questions/1003523/how-to-crack-the-password-of-a-zip-which-is-protected-with-a-password    not working